# PHP - How to assign a method with arguments dynamically to object?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code for example:

```
$sheet_data=Model::where('workbook_ord',"$workbook")->get();
```

I want to assign `where` block to `Model` dynamically like this:

```
$qry = 'where("workbook_ord","$workbook")';
```

and I want the query to become like this:

```
$sheet_data=Model::eval($qry)->get();
```

I know if I want to use method name dynamically, I can use that like this:

```
$qry = "where";
$sheet_data=Model::$qry('workbook_ord',"$workbook")->get();
```

But, I want to execute function including parametera defined in a string.

I hope there must be a way to do that.

Comment: not really clear what you want to do, parse a string into code? there is no standard function for this, you need to manually write an evaluator

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute a function by using a string or you want to **define** a function using a code string?

Comment: Sound like u need something like `DB::raw($qry)` but this method is very unsafe

Comment: @Ad5001Gameurcodeurautre Exactly, I want to execute a function using string.

Comment: @FaizanAli Just asking. Where would come the string from? If it comes from a user input it might not be a great idea of executing custom PHP with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the solution for the problem you asked for but you can use magic methods to achieve something similar.
For your specific case you can use [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) where you can call any pseudo method to be parsed inside `__callStatic` with the correspondent arguments.

```
class Model
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling static method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
}

Model::where('workbook_ord', 'test')
// will echo: Calling static method 'where' workbook_ord, test
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for.